# EntityMaterializerSource - Handling Datetime

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to rewrite a code that transforms dates, but I'm still learning C# and .NET, so I'll put part of my code here.

this code was made in net core 2.1

```
public class DateTimeKindEntityMaterializerSource : EntityMaterializerSource{private static readonly MethodInfo _normalizeMethod =typeof(DateTimeKindMapper).GetTypeInfo().GetMethod(nameof(DateTimeKindMapper.Normalize));
```

```
        private static readonly MethodInfo _normalizeNullableMethod =
            typeof(DateTimeKindMapper).GetTypeInfo().GetMethod(nameof(DateTimeKindMapper.NormalizeNullable));

        private static readonly MethodInfo _normalizeObjectMethod =
            typeof(DateTimeKindMapper).GetTypeInfo().GetMethod(nameof(DateTimeKindMapper.NormalizeObject));

        public override Expression CreateReadValueExpression(Expression valueBuffer, Type type, int index, IProperty property = null)
        //public override Expression CreateReadValueExpression(Expression valueBuffer, Type type, int index, IPropertyBase property = null)
        {
            if (type == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                return Expression.Call(
                    _normalizeMethod,
                    base.CreateReadValueExpression(valueBuffer, type, index, property));
            }
            if (type == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                return Expression.Call(
                    _normalizeNullableMethod,
                    base.CreateReadValueExpression(valueBuffer, type, index, property));
            }
            return base.CreateReadValueExpression(valueBuffer, type, index, property);
        }
        public override Expression CreateReadValueCallExpression(Expression valueBuffer, int index)
        {
            var readValueCallExpression = base.CreateReadValueCallExpression(valueBuffer, index);
            if (readValueCallExpression.Type == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                return Expression.Call(
                    _normalizeMethod,
                    readValueCallExpression);
            }
            if (readValueCallExpression.Type == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                return Expression.Call(
                    _normalizeNullableMethod,
                    readValueCallExpression);
            }
            if (readValueCallExpression.Type == typeof(object))
            {
                return Expression.Call(
                    _normalizeObjectMethod,
                    readValueCallExpression);
            }
            return readValueCallExpression;
        }
    }
```

```
//Classe Mapper
```

```
public class DateTimeKindMapper{public static DateTime Normalize(DateTime value)=> DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

```
    public static DateTime? NormalizeNullable(DateTime? value)
        => value.HasValue ? DateTime.SpecifyKind(value.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc) : (DateTime?)null;

    public static object NormalizeObject(object value)
        => value is DateTime dateTime ? Normalize(dateTime) : value;
}
```

This code was made in .net core 2.1, I need to transfer it to .net 6; Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Could you tell us where you get an error or get the result not as expected?

Comment: Looks like latest version (6, 7) of .Net core have changes to the contracts, may be if any articles with change details will help to solve the breaking changes immediately for all the migration applications. We were using `CreateReadValueExpression(Expression valueBuffer, Type type, int index, IPropertyBase property = null)` which is no more valid